# Reference a capturing group in a Sublime Text search expression

Tags: regex, syntax, sublimetext

I'm sure this has already been asked somewhere, but I can't find it.
What I want to know is if I can refer to a capturing group later in the same expression within Sublime Text.

For Example, the following works on https://regex101.com/:

```
(<)(h1|h3)(.*?)(\2)(>)
```

Matches

```
<h3 class="blah">Hi Blah</h3>
```

I'm using the `\2` to refer to the matching tag here.  In Sublime I've tried `$2`, `\2`, `\\2`, `\$2`, etc.  You get the idea.  Is this just not possible, or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks

**Edit:** Okay - I figured out what I was doing wrong.  I was using the `(?s)` *(dotall)* modifier and I was counting that as a capturing group.  So, `$3` should have been `$2`, `$2` should've been `$1`, etc.  My regexp was sufficiently complicated that I didn't notice until I tried it to address the comments in this question, and didn't have the dotall modifier in place.

I'll leave it up unless a mod wants to take it down, because I could see someone else having the same problem.  Ciao.

Comment: Do `ctrl`+`f` then `alt`+`r`. Then try.

Comment: @revo - Regexp is already enabled.

Comment: What happens when you do a search then?

Comment: @revo - see my addendum.  As is often the case, it was operator error.